# What happens when I restart a service via systemctl or init

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, init, systemctl

Im trying to understand the lifecycle of a process during the restart.

For eg:

If we issue the restart command

1. It'll kill the process id
2. remove or flush all the open files in the descriptors.
3. Close the TCP or Unix socket
4. Then start - all actual command will be triggered.

Can someone help to understand this in a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `SIGTERM` signal will be sent to the server process, with the expectation that the process will exit. It is up to the process itself to catch the signal and do whatever is needed to gracefully exit. I.e. the process itself should take care of flushing files, closing network connections it has open, etc.

If the process does not exit within a timeout limit, it is forcvly killed with a `SIGKILL` signal. The default value of the timeout is 90 seconds.